# Updating a Contact with EWS

Tags: dictionary, title, exchangewebservices, contacts

I have struggled to find out how to work with EWS and have managed to work out how to do just about everything I've wanted to. I am using EWS to manage contacts between a custom database and the Exchange server (2007). Adding and deleting works just fine, but I cannot update a contact. To workaround this, I deleted the contact and recreated it, but the problem comes in when the contact is edited via Outlook (or whatever else).

I tried to follow what this link says:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/ee693002(v=exchg.80).aspx

but I get an error saying that only one property can be updated. Then I update each property one at a time, and as soon as I try to update a phone number I get an error which says: "The element 'Updates' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types' has incomplete content."

Here is the code, basically:

```cs
ItemId itemId = contactToUpdate.Id;
Contact updateContact = Contact.Bind(service, itemId);
updateContact.PhoneNumbers[PhoneNumberKey.HomePhone] = customContact.HomeTelephone;
updateContact.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite);
```

Does anyone know why I get this error? Can anyone answer how to actually update an item? Is there documentation I have missed?

The version of the EWS dll's is 15.0.516.12.

Comment: If it helps, Microsoft can't code correctly against their own API either. I got this error from Outlook for Mac 2016.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the answer to this after much debugging. I'm not going to explore more to find out why, but you can't do this:

```cs
updateContact = Contact.Bind(service, itemId);
updateContact.PhoneNumbers[PhoneNumberKey.HomePhone] = customContact.HomePhone;
updateContact.PhoneNumbers[PhoneNumberKey.MobilePhone] = customContact.MobilePhone;
updateContact.PhoneNumbers[PhoneNumberKey.BusinessPhone] = customContact.BusinessPhone;
updateContact.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite);
```

You can, however, set only one phone number and then change the values for the other two while debugging (while on a break point). Weird.

Anyway, there is a problem - you can't update one of these dictionary values if the value does not change (that's the answer in short), so do a check first to see if the value changed. Next, if a value is an empty string, you need to rather save it as null. You also need to check whether the dictionary entry exists before trying to read its value.

```cs
string number;
bool numberFound;

numberFound = updateContact.PhoneNumbers.TryGetValue(PhoneNumberKey.HomePhone, out number);
if ((numberFound && number != customContact.HomePhone) ||
    (!numberFound && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(customContact.HomePhone)))
{
    updateContact = Contact.Bind(service, itemId);
    updateContact.PhoneNumbers[PhoneNumberKey.HomePhone] = customContact.HomePhone == "" ? null : customContact.HomePhone;
    updateContact.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite);
}
```

To update an address:

```cs
updateContact = Contact.Bind(service, itemId);
updateContact.PhysicalAddresses[PhysicalAddressKey.Home].Street = customContact.Street == "" ? null : customContact.Street;
updateContact.PhysicalAddresses[PhysicalAddressKey.Home].State = customContact.Suburb == "" ? null : customContact.Suburb;
updateContact.PhysicalAddresses[PhysicalAddressKey.Home].City = customContact.City == "" ? null : customContact.City;
updateContact.PhysicalAddresses[PhysicalAddressKey.Home].CountryOrRegion = customContact.Country == "" ? null : customContact.Country;
updateContact.PhysicalAddresses[PhysicalAddressKey.Home].PostalCode = customContact.AreaCode == "" ? null : customContact.AreaCode;
updateContact.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite);
```

This, in my opinion, is sloppy implementation of the API (and poor documentation).

<strike>The fact that an update needs to be performed for each property of an item could possibly be due to the server running Exchange 2007, but this has yet to be confirmed.</strike>

I tried with both version 14 and 15 of Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices with the same results.

**Update**

But wait, there's more.

I'm posting a lot of code to illustrate how to update different phone numbers, addresses, etc. The code also shows how to update (or set) title, gender, suffix and a custom property (user defined field - which if you want to appear in Outlook, you need to add the user defined field to the contacts folder).

Here is a complete, working piece of code:

```cs
Contact updateContact = Contact.Bind(service, itemId);
updateContact.GivenName = customContact.Name;
updateContact.Surname = customContact.Surname;

EmailAddress emailAddress;
bool emailAddressFound;

emailAddressFound = updateContact.EmailAddresses.TryGetValue(EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1, out emailAddress);
if (emailAddressFound && emailAddress.Address != customContact.Email)
{
    emailAddress.Address = customContact.Email == "" ? null : customContact.Email;
}
else if (!emailAddressFound && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(customContact.Email))
{
    updateContact.EmailAddresses[EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1] = customContact.Email;
}
updateContact.Initials = customContact.Initials;

string number;
bool numberFound;

numberFound = updateContact.PhoneNumbers.TryGetValue(PhoneNumberKey.HomePhone, out number);
if ((numberFound && number != customContact.HomePhone) || (!numberFound && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(customContact.HomePhone)))
{
    updateContact.PhoneNumbers[PhoneNumberKey.HomePhone] = customContact.HomePhone == "" ? null : customContact.HomePhone;
}
numberFound = updateContact.PhoneNumbers.TryGetValue(PhoneNumberKey.MobilePhone, out number);
if ((numberFound && number != customContact.CellPhone) || (!numberFound && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(customContact.CellPhone)))
{
    updateContact.PhoneNumbers[PhoneNumberKey.MobilePhone] = customContact.CellPhone == "" ? null : customContact.CellPhone;
}
numberFound = updateContact.PhoneNumbers.TryGetValue(PhoneNumberKey.BusinessPhone, out number);
if ((numberFound && number != customContact.WorkPhone) || (!numberFound && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(customContact.WorkPhone)))
{
    updateContact.PhoneNumbers[PhoneNumberKey.BusinessPhone] = customContact.WorkPhone == "" ? null : customContact.WorkPhone;
}

PhysicalAddressEntry phsicalAddress;
bool phsicalAddressFound;
int phsicalAddressLength = (customContact.Street + customContact.Suburb + customContact.City + customContact.Country + customContact.AreaCode).Length;
phsicalAddressFound = updateContact.PhysicalAddresses.TryGetValue(PhysicalAddressKey.Home, out phsicalAddress);
if (phsicalAddressFound)
{
    updateContact.PhysicalAddresses[PhysicalAddressKey.Home].Street = customContact.Street == "" ? null : customContact.Street;
    updateContact.PhysicalAddresses[PhysicalAddressKey.Home].State = customContact.Suburb == "" ? null : customContact.Suburb;
    updateContact.PhysicalAddresses[PhysicalAddressKey.Home].City = customContact.City == "" ? null : customContact.City;
    updateContact.PhysicalAddresses[PhysicalAddressKey.Home].CountryOrRegion = customContact.Country == "" ? null : customContact.Country;
    updateContact.PhysicalAddresses[PhysicalAddressKey.Home].PostalCode = customContact.AreaCode == "" ? null : customContact.AreaCode;
}
else if (!phsicalAddressFound && phsicalAddressLength > 0)
{
    updateContact.PhysicalAddresses[PhysicalAddressKey.Home] = homeAddress;
}
phsicalAddressLength = (customContact.BusinessStreet + customContact.BusinessSuburb + customContact.BusinessCity + customContact.BusinessCountry + customContact.BusinessAreaCode).Length;
phsicalAddressFound = updateContact.PhysicalAddresses.TryGetValue(PhysicalAddressKey.Business, out phsicalAddress);
if (phsicalAddressFound)
{
    updateContact.PhysicalAddresses[PhysicalAddressKey.Business].Street = customContact.BusinessStreet == "" ? null : customContact.BusinessStreet;
    updateContact.PhysicalAddresses[PhysicalAddressKey.Business].State = customContact.BusinessSuburb == "" ? null : customContact.BusinessSuburb;
    updateContact.PhysicalAddresses[PhysicalAddressKey.Business].City = customContact.BusinessCity == "" ? null : customContact.BusinessCity;
    updateContact.PhysicalAddresses[PhysicalAddressKey.Business].CountryOrRegion = customContact.BusinessCountry == "" ? null : customContact.BusinessCountry;
    updateContact.PhysicalAddresses[PhysicalAddressKey.Business].PostalCode = customContact.BusinessAreaCode == "" ? null : customContact.BusinessAreaCode;
}
else if (!phsicalAddressFound && phsicalAddressLength > 0)
{
    updateContact.PhysicalAddresses[PhysicalAddressKey.Business] = businessAddress;
}
updateContact.Birthday = customContact.Birthdate;
updateContact.WeddingAnniversary = customContact.MaritalStatusDate;
// Extended properties -------------------------------------------------------------
ExtendedPropertyDefinition extendedPropertyDefinition;
// Gender
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(customContact.Gender))
{
    extendedPropertyDefinition = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x3a4d, MapiPropertyType.Short);
    switch (customContact.Gender)
    {
        case "Male":
            updateContact.SetExtendedProperty(extendedPropertyDefinition, 2);
            break;
        case "Female":
            updateContact.SetExtendedProperty(extendedPropertyDefinition, 1);
            break;
        default:
            updateContact.SetExtendedProperty(extendedPropertyDefinition, 3);
            break;
    }
}
// Title
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(customContact.Title))
{
    extendedPropertyDefinition = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x3a45, MapiPropertyType.String);
    updateContact.SetExtendedProperty(extendedPropertyDefinition, customContact.Title);
}
// Suffix
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(customContact.Suffix))
{
    extendedPropertyDefinition = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x3a05, MapiPropertyType.String);
    updateContact.SetExtendedProperty(extendedPropertyDefinition, customContact.Suffix);
}
// Custom property
extendedPropertyDefinition = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.PublicStrings, "customProperty", MapiPropertyType.String);
updateContact.SetExtendedProperty(extendedPropertyDefinition, customContact.CustomProperty);
// File the contact
updateContact.Subject = customContact.Name + " " + customContact.Surname;
updateContact.DisplayName = customContact.Name + " " + customContact.Surname;
updateContact.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite);
```

Comment: Hi Marc,

Have you managed to clear an email address without getting this error message back from EWS? Error: "An object within a change description must contain one and only one property to modify."

If I set the email address to "-" it works fine.  As soon as I set it to String.Empty or null I get the error.

Comment: Hi Carl, As far as I know you have to set it to null if you want it empty. You can't set it to string.Empty. Also, only set the email address if it's found. Use Contact.EmailAddresses.TryGetValue() - this returns a bool. If there is no email address, you can't set it to null. Another thing to check is all your other properties - make sure they're all being set correctly too (and that they're found before trying). You may be setting one incorrectly and the email address fine.

Comment: @MarcK situation is still same after 6 years. I don't understand why you can't simply set all values in updateContact and save. Without thinking about if a particular field is updated or not. This is a ridiculous way of implementing an API I would say.

Comment: I try to set fax number using `contact.PhoneNumbers[PhoneNumberKey.BusinessFax]` but it dosent detect as fax number in Fax and Scan(show as invalid). I seams outlook save fax as a extended property but I dont know how to set that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the way Microsoft is using in [their example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee693002%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) to update the Business address:

```
PhysicalAddressEntry PABusinessEntry = new PhysicalAddressEntry();
PABusinessEntry.Street = "4567 Contoso Way";
PABusinessEntry.City = "Redmond";
PABusinessEntry.State = "OH";
PABusinessEntry.PostalCode = "33333";
PABusinessEntry.CountryOrRegion = "United States of America";
contact.PhysicalAddresses[PhysicalAddressKey.Business] = PABusinessEntry;
```

This way a new PhysicalAddressEntry-object is created which might solve your Problem.

(of course this does not help for the phone numbers.)

Comment: That looks like it would work perfectly. In my code if the address is not found I do assign a new address entry to the relevant one. I think if the entry exists you can't assign a new one like that. Perhaps when there are empty strings for some of the fields. I can't remember exactly, but there should be a good reason I didn't do this (as it is in my code if the entry doesn't exist). But I may be totally wrong. If you or anyone else uses your method to update an address, then let us know if it works.

Comment: Actually when I use this it works even when the pysicaladress already contained an item. So for me this works nicely.