# How to find a contact from Exchange Server using contact's email address

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, exchange-server

I want to update a contact's First Name, how can I find that contact using contact's email address.

The contacts are stored in `WellKnownFolderName.Contacts` folder.

Comment: There are various options to do that, without that you share here some starting point or research you have done I think nobody will jump in and share a complete code with you. So you should update your posting with some more infos and a code basis where you stuck with.

Comment: Thank you @BastianW, I will add some more info.

Comment: I found the solution in the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9480467/how-i-can-update-a-contact-item-in-exchange-web-api . The first solution is worked.

Comment: The post the solution here as an answer and accept it on your own. The this question can be closed and wouldn’t stay unanswered in the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution here:

[How I can update a contact item in Exchange Web Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9480467/how-i-can-update-a-contact-item-in-exchange-web-api)

The first solution posted by @Jakob Christensen.